# Maintaining build and deployment history in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-deployment

How can we maintain build and deployment history if we are planning to migrate the yml pipelines from one project to another in Azure DevOps?

Comment: You can't. Pipeline history is not portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can we maintain build and deployment history if we are planning to migrate the yml pipelines from one project to another in Azure DevOps?

I am afraid there is no such way to do this at this moment.

Currently, we can only export and import pipeline for the classic editor. For the yml pipelines, we could only copy the yml file to another repo. But neither classic editor nor yml can transplant history records.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]